# GWT on AppEngine - IncompatibleRemoteServiceException after method refactoring

Tags: java, google-app-engine, caching, gwt

I have an GWT application hosted on googles app engine. It was running fine until I renamed the RPC method "test()" and now I get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: greetServlet: An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: This application is out of date, 
please click the refresh button on your browser. ( Could not locate requested method 'test(java.lang.String, long)' in interface 'de.test.client.GreetingService' )
```

For some reason reason it is still looking for the old signature of the method. I already compiled and cleaned my project several times and redeployed it, I cleared the browser cache and tried different browsers. In Dev-Mode it works fine as well.

Is there some additional cache build into app engine or something? Does someone ever experience similar issues?

Comment: Have you cleared all the auto-generated stuff as suggested in my [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455516/issue-with-instalation-of-gwt-2-6/23456302#23456302). Have you updated  all the classes Async,Service ans ServiceImpl.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that this method's signature is the same in Service, ServiceAsync, and ServiceImpl. For example, make sure that it's Long and not "long" everywhere.